# How do I replicate this script being used on a Red Hat Vagrant box using a Ubuntu Vagrant box?

Tags: networking, scripts, dhcp, vagrant

I have a Vagrant box running a Node.js app for internal use at work.  It is currently running on a Red Hat 6.5 Linux Vagrant box but for reasons I need to migrate it to a Ubuntu 18 Vagrant box.  The script in question from the Vagrantfile is pasted below.  My understanding from the research I have done is that this will assign the DHCP Hostname on creation with the argument that is passed to the script which allows the box to be found at that address provided when I try to navigate to the app from an external machine.

I have found resources about changing the hostname in Ubuntu but all of the changes only seem to have any effect internal to the box, is there a way to replicate this in Ubuntu so that a machine outside of my Vagrant box reaches the app via a hostname of my choosing?

```
$config_dhcp = <<SCRIPT
  config_hostname=$1
  dhcphostname=`less /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1|grep DHCP_HOSTNAME`
  if [ "$dhcphostname" == "" ]; then
    echo "DHCP_HOSTNAME=$config_hostname">>/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
    /sbin/service network restart
    echo "set `less /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1|grep DHCP_HOSTNAME`"
  else
    echo "$dhcphostname already set"
    fi
SCRIPT
```